# Oracle VM and live storage migration (like storage vMotion on VMware), is it possible?

Tags: storage, live-migration, oraclevm

I have to migrate VMs to new storage for a client. Hypervisor is Oracle VM, versions 3.3 & 3.4. Haven't access to the machines yet, I'm searching for info for live storage migration on this platform, Oracle VM.

In Oracle docs, [Oracle VM 3.4 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E64076_01/E64081/html/vmcon-vm-move.html) this doesn't seem possible (only if the VM is stopped). In [Oracle VM datasheet](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/virtualization/ovm-server-for-x86-459312.pdf?source=:so:tw:or::TWEMEA) it mentions, Storage live VM migration, perform live migrations of running virtual machines that have virtual disks on local storage.

So I am confused. Does anybody have any experience of live storage migration on Oracle VM, versions 3.3 & 3.4?